# Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:http" is not handled by plugins

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, oauth

I try to do this I'm geting webpack compiled with 10 errors and 1 warning.the problem displayed in the node buffer.I update the node version and also the npm but still display the same error.
I used the fetch to get the access token from the auth0.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (formData.authMethod === 'UserIDPassword') {
      try {
        const invitationResponse = await sendInvitation(formData.whitelistedDomains);
        console.log('Invitation sent:', invitationResponse);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending invitation:', error);
      }
    } else {
        console.log(' Handle form submission for other authentication methods');
    }
  };
const sendInvitation = async (domains) => {
    const domainArray = domains.split(',').map((domain) => domain.trim());
    try {
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: `{
          "client_id":"${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_ID}",
          "client_secret":"${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_CLIENT_SECRET}",
          "audience":"${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_API_Audience}",
          "grant_type":"client_credentials"}`
      };
      const response = await fetch(`https://${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_DOMAIN}/oauth/token`,options);
      const data = await response.json();
      const tokenResponse = data.access_token;
      const YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_MANAGEMENT_DOMAIN;
      const managementApiUrl = `https://${YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}/api/v2`;
      const createUserUrl = `${managementApiUrl}/users`;
      const createInviteUrl = `${managementApiUrl}/invitations`;
      const userResponse = await fetch(createUserUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: formData.email,
          username: formData.username,
        }),
      });

      const user = await userResponse.json();
      const inviteResponse = await fetch(createInviteUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          user_id: user.user_id,
          inviter_id: 'YOUR_USER_ID', 
          invitee_email: formData.email,
          invited_domains: domainArray,
        }),
      });

      const invitation = await inviteResponse.json();

      return invitation;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending invitation:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
};

export default RegistrationForm;
```

[Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:http" is not handled by plugins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDnzc.png)